# Sifting through CSV files for time stamps

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am fairly new to python but have a problem I'd like to solve but need a little bit of help.

I need to ask a user which directory path they want which I've figured out that part but....

From there I need to figure out a way to ask a user for a specific date/time range day-month-year, hours:minutes:seconds then filter out which csv files are in that range.

From there, I need my program to go into the filtered CSV files and look at time stamps recorded in the csv files.

From those time stamps I need to calculate if there are any gaps from the end of one csv file to the start of next.

If there are gaps I need to return a statement that indicates how long the gap is.

I've seen a few things, but am having trouble putting it all together!

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Dask data frames (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), which works on top of Pandas data frames.

Without going much deeper into Dask you need to know that it works in lazy mode, which means that will not do any processing until it is explicitly triggered with compute method. That makes the coding slightly different from Pandas.

Following example solves the part of reading multiple files and find gaps. The datafiles (that you can find here: https://github.com/mchiuminatto/stackoverflow/tree/master/data)
are OHLC data with frequency of D (one day) so the gap condition is that the difference between any two consecutive dates is more then 1 day.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

# read all the csv files in the directory
# how much is loaded into memory is managed by Dask.

df = dd.read_csv('./data/*.csv')  
                                 
df['date_time'] = dd.to_datetime(df['Time (UTC)'])
df['Time (UTC)'] = dd.to_datetime(df['Time (UTC)'])
df = df.set_index('Time (UTC)')
df['dif'] = df['date_time'] - df['date_time'].shift(1)  # calculates gaps

# no data transformation is performed until you execute compute.
df.compute().head(5)
```

[image]

To check one record:

```
df.loc['2020-01-06 22:00:00'].compute()
```

[image]

Filter the periods with more than one day of difference

```
_mask = df['dif'] > '1 days' # time unit can be adjusted
df_gap = df[_mask].compute()  # now we persist transformations in a Pandas df: df_gap

df_gap.head(5)
```

[image]

```
df_gap.tail(5)
```

[image]